# Error con variable de bloque no establecida

Tags: vba

Tengo el error 91 en `VBA` con el siguiente código:

```
Dim i, c, b, a, 

With wsMissingSCM2.ListObjects("tblReportData2")
    .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight6"
    '
    ' LocationColumn
    '
    i = 1
    .ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter 'ERROR HERE
    .HeaderRowRange.Columns(i).Value = "Missing Item"
    .ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.ColumnWidth = 14
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando defines la propiedad `.DataBodyRange.HorizontalAlignment` no sabe a que objeto lo deseas realizar ya que realizaste otra asignación anteriormente, `i = 1`, por esa razón obtienes el error [With block variable not set (Error 91)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506(v=vs.60).aspx) :

Cambia tu código, estableciendo primeramente las propiedades de `wsMissingSCM2.ListObjects("tblReportData2")` y posteriormente el valor de `i` :

```
  With wsMissingSCM2.ListObjects("tblReportData2")
    .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight6"
    .ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter 
    .HeaderRowRange.Columns(i).Value = "Missing Item"
    .ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.ColumnWidth = 14

    i = 1
```